# How to create an encrypted data bag in Chef

Tags: windows, chef-infra, tr

I know that this topic has answers here, but I've got some problems and I would like to start from scratch.

First step is to create a key file:

```
openssl rand -base64 512 | tr -d '\r\n' > encrypted_data_bag_secret
```

but how to run this command on Windows? The `tr` command is not recognised.

I generated an openssl key and copied it to a txt file, then I was doing step by step like in Chef Docs but it doesn't work - a data bag isn't encrypted. I think I have to run this command above, but I don't know why to do this on windows

Comment: You don't have to do it on windows, and for tests purposes a simple string 'mykey' in a txt file is enough. Without more details on what you did and how you did configure your system (mainly knife) it's impossible to give better advice.

Comment: Ok. So the next step is running a command: knife data bag create mydatabag secretstuff --secret-file C:\Users\admin\chef-repo\data_bags/key.txt. I receive in return: Created data_bag_item[secretstuff]. I go to chef manager end edit this item. No I want to check my ecryption so I run this command: knife data bag show mydatabag secretstuff. And my item isn't encrypted. What is wrong?

Comment: I can't have any idea without knowing your `knife.rb` configuration file. If the encrypted_data_bag_secret configuration points to your key file, it will use it automatically...

Comment: well... i have nothing connected with encryption in my knife.rb. There are: current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "admin"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/admin.pem"
validation_client_name   "name"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/name.pem"
chef_server_url          "[my server]"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]

Comment: @Tensibai ok, i finally got this encryption. But there is another problem. When a create a data bag in a standart way ( `knife data bag create sth sth` ) I can see this bags on a chef server. But when I do it with encryption ( `knife data bag create mydatabag secretstuff --secret-file C:\Users\admin\chef-repo\data_bags/key.txt` ) there are no new data bag on my chef manager. Why??

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent in pure Ruby would be:

```
C:\chef\embedded\bin\ruby -e 'require "securerandom"; STDOUT.write(SecureRandom.base64(512))' > C:\chef\encrypted_data_bag_secret
```

Tweak the `C:\chef` path as appropriate, I don't have a Windows box handy to check the current default paths.